# monic polynomials and fields and quotient of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $h$ be a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ of degree $m\geq 1$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. $\mathbb{F}[x]/(h)$ is a field if and only if $(h)$ is irreducible.

Forward direction:

Suppose $\mathbb{F}[x]/(h)$ is a field then $(h)$ is a maximal ideal.  Suppose $h=fg$, for polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$. Then, $(h)\subseteq (f)\subseteq \mathbb{F}[x]$. Since $A$ is maximal, $(h)=(f)$ or $(f)=\mathbb{F}[x]$. If $(h)=(f)$ then by uniquness $h=f$ and so the degree of $g$ must be $0$. If $(f)=\mathbb{F}[x]$ then $f$ is a unit and so must have degree $0$.  Hence $h$ is irreducible.

How do I show the backwards direction? Can someone do it without using gcd?

Comment: "By uniqueness $h=f$". Uniquenesss of what? $x-1 = (2x-2)(\frac{1}{2})$. And $(x-1)=(2x-2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Is $2x-2$ equal to $x-1$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin monic, irreducible polynomials uniquely generate maximal ideals in $\mathbb{F}[x]$. But that means I need to show $f$ is monic and irreducible....

Comment: Is that meant to answer either of my questions? (Irreducible polynomials generate maximal ideals, monic or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backwards direction goes like this:

Let $h$ be irreducible and assume we have an ideal $\mathfrak{a} = (a)$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ (this works because $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a PID), such that $(h) \subset \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathbb{F}[x]$. Then there exists some $c \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $h=ac$. Since $h$ is irreducible, we have $a \in (\mathbb{F}[x])^\times$ or $c \in (\mathbb{F}[x])^\times$. In the first case, we get $\mathfrak{a}=\mathbb{F}[x]$ and in the second case we get $\mathfrak{a}=(h)$. So $(h)$ is maximal, hence $\mathbb{F}[x]/(h)$ is a field. I leave it up to you to fill in any details.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}[x]^{\times}$?

Comment: It's the set of invertible elements of $\mathbb{F}[x]$, i.e. $(\mathbb{F}[x])^\times := \{ f \in \mathbb{F}[x] \mid \exists g \in \mathbb{F}[x], \text{ such that } fg=1 \}$. In this case, since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, we have $(\mathbb{F}[x])^\times = \mathbb{F}\setminus \{0\}$.